# Are path integrals integrals with countable or uncountable infinite dimensions?

Tags: mathematical-physics, path-integral, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

[Path integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) are integrals with infinite dimensions. But I recently became confused about if the number of dimensions are discrete/countable or continuous/uncountable. I always thought it should be continuous, because we are integrating over the space of possible functions, but then I saw that path integrals are sometimes written like
$$
\lim_{x->\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{ ... \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{ G[f] } }\prod_x df(x)
$$
implying that the product of dimensions is a countable infinity. So are path integrals integrals of countable infinite dimensions? If so could one imagine/define also path integrals for uncountable/continuous infinite number of dimensions?

Comment: The (naïve) definition of path integrals is through a limit of a **countable** infinite number of integrals (by slicing the path).  In the limit, a countable infinite turns into an uncountable infinite, but the actual limit is not (always) well-defined. Therefore, path integrals should be understood as a countable infinite and a formal limit. Any other notation is, well, notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lattice notation $\prod_x \mathrm{d}f(x)$ is just a heuristic notation, it doesn't tell you anything about the actual path integral measure, which is in the simplest case of non-relativistic quantum mechanics the [conditional Wiener measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space) on the space of continuous paths.

As a complete and separable infinite-dimensional space, the dimension of this space as a vector space is uncountable, but it possesses a countable [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis).

The path integrals of fields usually do not exist in any rigorous sense. Where they do, as for example in two and three dimensions for the scalar field (see the work of Glimm/Jaffe), the integral is supposed to be taken over the dual of the Schwartz functions (the tempered distributions) on space with respect to the Gaußian measure associated to the covariance operator of the fields. The tempered distributions are also complete and separable.

Comment: So path integrals are understood as having uncountable/continuous  infinite dimensions?

Comment: @asmaier: The function space they integrate over is uncountably infinite-dimensional, yes. It doesn't make sense to say the *integral* has this dimension.